# How to mock a feign interface with Mockito and return http status 404

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mockito, integration-testing, spring-cloud-feign

im trying to write some integration tests where i need to mock some feign interfaces and using them with MockMvc in my integration tests.
To mock them and deliver a certain result with the http status 200 is no problem and works fine. Example

```
    @Test
    public void testSomething() throws Exception {
            final List<TestDto> testData = Arrays.asList(TEST_DATA_1, TEST_DATA_2);

            when(testFeignClient.listSomething(any(), any()))
            .thenReturn(Page.<TestDto>builder()
            .size(testData.size())
            .totalElements(testData.size())
            .content(testData)
            .build());

            mockMvc.perform(
                            withDefaultRequestHeaders(get("/someTestMethod/find/{testId}", testId)))
                            .andExpect(status().isOk())
                            .andExpect(header()
                                            .string(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, startsWith(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE)))
                            .andExpect(jsonPath("_embedded.test[0].testId").value(TEST_DATA_1.getId()))
                            .andExpect(jsonPath("_embedded.test[1].testId").value(TEST_DATA_2.getId()))
                            .andReturn();
```

Now im searching for a way to mock the feign interface in that way that i can simulate other http status codes than 20x like 404 without delivering a (body) result. Was already searching a while but couldn't find anything yet.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Wiremock seems like what you are looking for.